# next.js ISR creates response time up to 60 seconds

Tags: next.js, bitbucket

we have a reached a limit when it comes to build times within our CI/CD. We have pre-rendered 9k pages and we have switched to ISR that we can update and generate on the fly the less relevant pages.

During small load test we have seen a huge drop of the overall performance of the whole next.js app. Weird was: All servers never died. The load test also end up in timeouts, which the webserver somehow queued. We have seen build time on some pages up to 60 seconds and after then it were delivered and were available on cache.

has anyone faced a similar issue? Also someone an idea how we can increase the horse if we use as CI/CD bitbucket to decrease build time?

Answer (score 0):

I faced a very similar issue for a large ecomerce / price comparison site with around about 180k pages that all need to be constantly updated to display the correct price / relevant data.

The problem we had was that when revalidation pages in the background which in our case was easily no less than 100 pages a second the server would take an extremely long time to generate them pages and would also cause actually network request for pages / apps that already exist to become very slow.

I would recommend one of three ways depending on your hosting availability and how complex you want the solution to be

1. Vertical scaling.
2. Horizontal scaling.
3. Custom isr implementation with a custom server

1 and 2 are basically just either paying for more powerful servers or distributing the app across multiple servers

3 (which was our choice). We have implemented a [custom server](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/configuring/custom-server) and insted or using getstaticprops with revalidation, instead used getServerSidePropson each page. This has allowed us to the store the page contents in a cache database. This has been extremely performent for us as it has allowed us to generate the pages outside of the actualy server that is returning responses. This means regardless of the amount of pages that we are generating in the background inside a diffrent version of the site that is running, it has no impact of the server that is returning the pages to the user